# xCP2.0 Java Service not working - IDfSession is null

Tags: java, business-process-management, documentum

I'm currently working on a xCP 2.0 project with Documentum 7.0 and I'm trying to run a Java Service inside a workflow. The Java Service works alright when the function I use does no more than return a "some_string" String. But as soon as I try the actual thing and use documentum specific Objects like:

```
IDfSession mySession = getSession();
```

I get these exceptions right here:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke the method 'test' from
>   interface 'class com.gemp1.Test' from BOF module 'gemp1_xCPJava' in
>   Process Template: 'Peticion de Nuevo Producto v2' - Activity: 'Execute
>   Java Service'. Workitem: '4a015abd80004959' Workflow: 'Peticion de
>   Nuevo Producto v2 2014-12-18' - '4d015abd8000411e' Activity: 'Execute
>   Java Service' - '4c015abd8002e358' Process: 'Peticion de Nuevo
>   Producto v2' - '4b015abd8002c56c' java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke the method 'test' from
>   interface 'class com.gemp1.Test' from BOF module 'gemp1_xCPJava'   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.AbstractService.execute(AbstractService.java:98)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.services.BPSIntegrationFramework.executeService(BPSIntegrationFramework.java:260)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.services.BPSIntegrationFramework.executeMethod(BPSIntegrationFramework.java:92)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.services.BPSIntegrationMethod.executeMethod(BPSIntegrationMethod.java:26)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.GenericWorkflowMethod.execute(GenericWorkflowMethod.java:129)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.GenericWorkflowMethod.execute(GenericWorkflowMethod.java:355)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.GenericWorkflowMethod.execute(GenericWorkflowMethod.java:70)
>   at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DfMethodRunner.runIt(Unknown Source)
>   at com.documentum.mthdservlet.AMethodRunner.runAndReturnStatus(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.invokeMethod(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DoMethod.doPost(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) **Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke the method 'test' from
>   interface 'class com.gemp1.Test' from BOF module 'gemp1_xCPJava'   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.bof.runtime.BOFClient.invokeMethod(BOFClient.java:121)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.bof.runtime.BofModuleService.executeServiceOperation(BofModuleService.java:133)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.AbstractService.executeServiceInternal(AbstractService.java:122)
>   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.AbstractService.execute(AbstractService.java:79)
>   ... 32 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)   at
>   com.documentum.bps.outbound.bof.runtime.BOFClient.invokeMethod(BOFClient.java:112)
>   ... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.documentum.fc.client.DfSingleDocbaseModule.getSession(DfSingleDocbaseModule.java:58)
>   at com.gemp1.Test.test(Test.java:11)   ... 40 more**

My Java class:

```
package com.gemp1;

import com.documentum.fc.client.*;
import com.documentum.fc.common.DfException;

public class Test extends DfSingleDocbaseModule {

    public String test() {
        String result = "Hello12345";
        return result;
    }

    public String[] getUsers() throws DfException {
        String docbaseUsers[] = new String[200];

        IDfCollection coll = null;
        IDfSession mySession = getSession();
        String myQuery = "select user_name from dm_user";
        IDfQuery myDFQuery = new DfQuery(myQuery);
        coll = myDFQuery.execute(mySession, IDfQuery.DF_QUERY);
        int i=0;
        while (coll.next()) {
            docbaseUsers[i] = coll.getString("user_name");
            i++;
        }
        return docbaseUsers;
    }
}
```

And finally my javamodule file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nsJavaModule:JavaModule xmlns:nsJavaModule="http://xcp.emc.com/javamodule" urn="urn:gemp1:com.emc.xcp.artifact.javamodule.category:Artifacts/Java Modules/xCPJava.javamodule" categoryId="com.emc.xcp.artifact.javamodule.category" name="xCPJava" label="xCPJava" implementationClass="com.gemp1.Test">
    <implementationJars contentPath="content/modules/xCPJava.jar"/>
    <implementationJars contentPath="content/modules/dfc.jar"/>
</nsJavaModule:JavaModule>
```

Am I missing something?